# Problem in getting field value from res.getBody()

Tags: community

how could i parse my web api response from res.getBody() into my custom object field by field.
And whenever i go to use JSON.serialiser() and JSON.deserialiser() there is error that "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].serialize(String)".
So please give me response fast.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. You might get more help if 1. you pose one specific question that the community can help you with (this post is a couple questions and is quite broad) and 2. don't be demanding and ask "give me response fast." People here love to help, but help them help you!

Answer (score 1):

On the error, it looks like you have a String variable named "json" or "JSON" (the Apex language itself is case insensitive) that is hiding the JSON class name. Your can work around that problem by including the [System](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm) namespace:

```
Object o = ...;
String json = ...;
String s = System.JSON.serialize(o);
```

Or you can rename your variable.

You need to provide more information to get a useful answer to "how could i parse...".